# allow user to select image for facebook like button

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to let a user pick which image for the "Like" post they will create when using a like button on a site?  I specified multiple og:image tags and the facebook linter is correctly displaying all the images, but when I click the like button, it doesn't give the option to pick which image I'd like to use.

Comment: @FFrewin have you tried using a URL shortener for the link and then sharing the short URL? [Some dude stumbled across that as a fix to this problem](https://forum.hootsuite.com/hootsuite/topics/multiple_facebook_image_options).